# {"Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt."}

Tags: .net, winforms, unity-container

I have built a simple application framework around Unity.  I.e.  Form and user controls are discribed as xml and built dynamically.  I have a form which contains a ComboBox which when closed causes the error detailed below.  The problem does not occur if the ComboBox is substituted for a ListBox control.

Some googling raised some reports of a patch which I didn't manage to install.. [KB923028](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/923028)

> {"Attempted to read or write protected
>   memory. This is often an indication
>   that other memory is corrupt."}

Stacktrace:

```
   at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.CallWindowProc(IntPtr wndProc, IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DefWndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.DefWndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmCommand(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
   at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(Int32 dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)
   at DPOSSQL.Program.Main() in C:\VSSData\DPOS SQL\DPOS SQL\Program.cs:line 46
   at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(Assembly assembly, String[] args)
   at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this kind of thing when a control uses an XP/Vista style and is then run on an older version of Windows.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this error when I install a new font on my system. Have you installed a new font, or a program that installed new fonts recently?

Do other .net programs run correctly? If not, your bet best is probably to reinstall the .NET framework.

Answer (score 0):

Just hit this on Windows XP when trying to switch the system display to "Extra Large Fonts" while my .NET application was running.

Seems likely that this is related to a malformed font or similar.

```
Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
Source: System.Windows.Forms
   at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(Int32 dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
```